# python unicode beginner : how to print out a series of letters?

Tags: python, unicode, iteration

I'de like to iterate through a list and print it out (for later use with the curses library) :

- U+0080 ... U+00FF: Latin-1 Supplement
- U+0100 ... U+017F: Latin Extended-A
- U+0180 ... U+024F: Latin Extended-B
- U+0250 ... U+02AF: IPA Extensions
- U+02B0 ... U+02FF: Spacing Modifier Letters
- U+0300 ... U+036F: Combining Diacritical Marks
- U+0370 ... U+03FF: Greek and Coptic
- U+0400 ... U+04FF: Cyrillic
- U+0500 ... U+052F: Cyrillic Supplement
- U+0530 ... U+058F: Armenian
- U+0590 ... U+05FF: Hebrew
- U+0600 ... U+06FF: Arabic
- U+0700 ... U+074F: Syriac
- U+0750 ... U+077F: Arabic Supplement
- U+0780 ... U+07BF: Thaana
- U+07C0 ... U+07FF: NKo
- U+0800 ... U+083F: Samaritan
- U+0900 ... U+097F: Devanagari
- U+0980 ... U+09FF: Bengali
- U+0A00 ... U+0A7F: Gurmukhi
- U+0A80 ... U+0AFF: Gujarati
- U+0B00 ... U+0B7F: Oriya
- U+0B80 ... U+0BFF: Tamil
- U+0C00 ... U+0C7F: Telugu
- U+0C80 ... U+0CFF: Kannada
- U+0D00 ... U+0D7F: Malayalam

But in the python documentation there's just about how to declare a string, not how to create it dynamically (like in a loop). I'm sorry if it's a beginner's question... but I don't know how to do it.

Thanks again!

Comment: I've edited your question, as you clearly do not mean UTF-8, but Unicode. That's different things. The U+ codes you mention above are not UTF8, they are Unicode code points.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What about : http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html

```
for i in xrange(0x80, 0xFF):
    print unichr(i)
```

Comment: Note that, for that to work, your standard output must be connected to a properly configured terminal, in such a way that python can detect the terminal's encoding (check `sys.stdout.encoding`). It will fail if you redirect the output to, say, a file.